# If $L_2L_1$ is accepted by a DFA, is $L_1$ too?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

> Given that $L_2, L_2L_1$ are accepted by a DFA, is $L_1$ accepted by a DFA too?

What is the general approach to such question? 
What if instead of $\cdot$ we are given that $L_2 \cup L_1$ is accepted?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should try to think of how you might construct a DFA to recognize $L_1$ given DFAs for $L_2$ and $L_2 L_1$, and if this looks too hard, narrow the source of the difficulty and try to elicit a counterexample that makes it impossible.  Play around with simple cases like single-letter alphabets, or cases where $L_2$ is very simple (empty, full), see whether it's true in these restricted domains.

Comment: Then the cup example is false. Because if we take $L_1$ as the empty language, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is the empty language, both are accepted by a DFA, but if $L_2$ is for example something that isn't accepted, then that just disproves it, yes?

Comment: No, if $L_1=\varnothing$, then $L_1\cup L_2=L_2$.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry.

Comment: Then my example applies to the $\cdot$ example, sorry, long day of lectures!

Comment: @TheNotMe Yes, it does.  You probably want to switch the roles of $L_2$ and $L_1$, though.

Comment: Indeed.
Now, what sort of languages are not accepted? -only- irregular ones, am I correct?

Comment: The answer for the original question is no, of course. For the additional — yes, of course.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko What exactly do you mean by the additional question?  Surely not the variant with $L_2 \cup L_1$?

Comment: @ErickWong Exactly that. Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of 'accepted language', but I think it means that all words from that language are accepted.

Comment: For the $\cup$ example I can take $L_2$ as $\Sigma^*$ and $L_1 = \{a^nb^n\}$ and that disproves the theory. No?

Comment: @TheNotMe Looks good, if you'd like to write up a solution you're quite welcome to answer your own question.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko More precisely, it's the set of all words accepted by the DFA (by your previous comments, perhaps you were thinking of a subset relation rather than equality).  It's important that not only is everything in $L_1$ accepted, but also everything outside of $L_1$ is rejected.

Comment: @EricWong So, the question was actually whether A·B=A => A=B? I got confused by the DFA in the question.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Ummm, not sure how $A\cdot B = A \implies A=B$ arises from the previous discussion?

Comment: @ErickWong Author gives that DFA accepts AB and A, which means (as you said) that AB=A. And asks whether B is accepted, which means that it's again the same language.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Ah, now I understand.  You're interpreting "is accepted by a DFA" to refer to a single specific DFA, but I read it as just a synonym for "is regular".  It's true that the first half of the question (up to the comma) is grammatically poor, leading to this ambiguity.  But it's also fair to say that the second half (starting from the comma) makes no reference to the DFA or DFAs mentioned in the first half.

Comment: @ErickWong Wow, thank you, my English failed me. So the question was just about regularity. Then everybody except me was right =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the $\cdot$ example, it is obviously wrong. One can take $L_2 = \emptyset$ and $L_1$ as any non-regular language.
For the $\cup$ example, it is also wrong. One can take $L_2 = \Sigma^*$ and $L_1$ as any non-regular language.

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong even if you assume that $L_1$, $L_1 \cup L_2$ and $L_1L_2$ are all regular languages, even on a one-letter alphabet $\{a\}$. Take $L_1 = a^*$ and $L_2$ a non regular language containing the empty word. Then $L_1 = L_1 \cup L_2 = L_1L_2 = a^*$.